# What is this package for bread saying?

Tags: meaning

It has a little journal on it that seems to be written by the founder, and it begins "My lasting memory of that trip to France in 1952, is of sensuality. Today, one would have to step off an aeroplane on the other side of the world to experience such an impact on the senses. There was a strangely exotic smell...."

It sounds as if in 1952 people didn't have to go to France to experience the exoticness of France, but it doesn't make sense at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: A long time ago the founder *did* go to France, and smelled a strangely exotic smell. In the intervening decades, the world has gotten a lot smaller, and today, you'd have to travel much farther away than France to have a similarly exotic experience. Bali, say.

Comment: They're saying that to them, their 1952 trip to france was as exotic as a trip to the other side of the world would be today.

Comment: That totally makes sense, but I bought this bread in Japan, so France is literally the other side of the world. Or is this just being used as a common phrase for the very distant place?

Comment: @ezirousuzu The distance is not relative to where you bought it, but to where the founder started his/her journey.

Comment: Unless you're  native to Bali, in which case Bali isn't exotic. Brooklyn would be exotic to the Balinese.

Comment: He's saying "Get all emotional and buy my bread, even though you can't smell it at all in this plastic bag."  (Seriously, it's an attempt to make you believe you're smelling an exotic bread, even though all you smell is the supermarket.)

Comment: @Lawrence That bread was a local product. It might sound a little odd that they have foreign texts on it, but they do for better designs. So I assumed the founder started his career in his home country, but it may be different.

Comment: @ezirousuzu If English isn't the writer's native language, there might be something lost in translation. The parallel might be between travel by boat and travel by aeroplane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the author is suggesting that going to somewhere like France has become so banal and easy now-a-days that it isn't really a shock to the senses anymore.